# RCPT TO: <rcpt@host> SMTP syntax

Tags: java, smtp

I have a bit of code that fails to successfully execute, and I am failing to understand why.

This function:

```
public void send(Envelope envelope) throws IOException
{
        String CRLF = "\r\n";
    sendCommand("MAIL FROM:"+ envelope.Sender + CRLF, 250);
    
    //error occuring here. "Return Code:500 #5.5.1 command not recognized"
    sendCommand("RCPT TO:" + envelope.Recipient + CRLF, 250);
    sendCommand("DATA", 354);
    toServer.print(envelope.Message.Headers + CRLF);
    toServer.print(envelope.Message.Body + CRLF);
    toServer.print("." +CRLF);
}
```

The above code calls this Function:

```
private void sendCommand(String command, int rc) throws IOException
{
    /* Write command to server */
    toServer.print(command + CRLF);
    
    /*read reply from server. */
    String line = fromServer.readLine();
    
    System.err.println("Request: " + command);
    System.err.println("Return Code:" + line);
    
    
    /*
     * Check that the server's reply code is the same as the parameter rc.
     * If not, throw an IOException.
     */
    if (!line.substring(0,3).equals(rc+""))
    {
        throw new IOException();
    }
}
```

And the inforation is transmitted thus:

```
Socket connection = new Socket(envelope.DestAddr, SMTP_PORT); 
    fromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    toServer = new PrintStream(connection.getOutputStream());
```

I am using the same From and To. And for some reason the RCPT TO: command is met with an error saying:

> "Return Code:500 #5.5.1 command not recognized"

**EDIT:** I did try them manually by telnetting

Comment: Did you try the same commands in the same order bty telnetting the host on port 25??

Comment: Obviously `envelope.Recipient` is not what you think it is - you need to check it.

Comment: Which ... isn't valid. You seem to have a mental block regarding the `<` and `>` you typed manually ;)

Comment: I just tested it both ways. The mail server is smart enough to add <> for me so that is clearly not the issue

Comment: Duh, I just caught it. Answer below :)

Comment: Lol thanks. I hadnt refreshed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending `\r\n` twice - once in `send()` when you're building the string, and once in `sendCommand()` in the `print()` call.

The second `\r\n` triggers the `500 5.5.1 Unrecognized command.`